# How to use other subscriptions to create new web site on Azure

Tags: azure, subscription, azure-web-app-service

In the new Azure Portal, people who with 3-Month Free Trial subscription can create up to 10 websites.
I create a website using 3-Month Free Trial subscription already. Otherwise I have other subscriptions like Windows Azure MSDN and Pay-As-You-Go, but how can I create new website using these other subscriptions.
I mean, when I try to create new website, there's no way to select subscriptions, and the new website is always under 3-Month Free Trial subscription.

Comment: Have you enabled the preview features to your MSDN or Pay-as-you-go subscription?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your above description, I am not sure if you have a Paid Windows Azure Subscription. 
So what you really need is to get a paid subscription first and that you can get directly from Windows Azure Account section at Portal. Paid subscription means you will have to pay for any other services (i.e. storage, bandwidth etc as applicable) you will use. You will have 10 free websites and will not pay anything if you just use Windows Azure Websites (ONLY) but still pay for Azure storage or anything else.

If you have multiple subscription associated with one single live account and accounts have Preview features enabled then I can see that new Management Portal does not have a way to select specific subscription to create a service. You would need to login to older portal and setup different Live ID for different subscription in "User Management" section and then use that specific Live ID to access specific subscription to create your website. (Note: The preview Portal is still in preview that's why such functionality in not available yet).

Answer (score 1):

The new subscription needs to have the Preview features enabled:

"All you have to do is activate the Web Sites preview on the new subscription by going to Account (View my bill) -> Preview Features: https://account.windowsazure.com/PreviewFeatures "

From:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsazurewebsitespreview/thread/6fc50df9-9d71-472b-b39b-a051fb1f8560